# CSS selector. I must not be understanding this correctly

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am having trouble targeting this fifth anchor tag. I simply want to separate the final anchor visually from the rest of the list but I still want it grouped (obviously by the ul)

Any help is appreciated!

```
ul>
    <li>PORTFOLIO:</li>
    <li><a href="index.html">layout</a></li>
    <li><a href="logo.html">logo design</a></li>
    <li><a href="print.html">print design</a></li>
    <li><a href="mailto:blahblahblah&#64;yahoo.com">Contact Me</a></li>
</ul>



#mainNav a {
    color:#428896;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#mainNav ul>:first-child {
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#mainNav ul li:nth-child(5) {  
  padding-left: 50px;
}
```

Comment: What browser? That isn't supported in all of them.

Comment: Your CSS is wrong. `padding:left: 50px;` should be `padding-left: 50px;`

Comment: `ul>:first-child` i'm no CSS expert but is this valid? shouldn't it be `ul>li:first-child` ??

Comment: @rlemon: Yes, `ul>:first-child` is the same as `ul>*:first-child`.

Comment: You need to be careful when pasting your code, and clear in explaining what you're looking for. As it currently stands, there are a number of mistakes and inconsistencies that may lead to the wrong assumptions.

Comment: After the corrections you’ve made, the code works on Firefox for example, naturally assuming that we wrap the elements inside a container with `id=mainNav`. So what might be the remaining problem(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the last anchor why just not use:

```
ul li:last-child a{
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:red;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4fs2s/

And in your example ul doesn't have #mainNav id

Comment: last-child has bad IE support.

Comment: I thought that nth-child is badly supported in IE too

Comment: @JezenThomas: No, it's exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is fine. The property for the left padding is `padding-left`, not `padding:left`.

See this fiddle > http://jsfiddle.net/QL7ds/

Answer (score 0):

Is it a typo that your last `li` is not closed?

Comment: Even if it is, it doesn't affect the DOM in any way unless there's something else following the `</a>` tag.

Comment: I apologize. the last </li> was in my actual code but was not copied over correctly

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is wrong. `padding:left: 50px;` should be `padding-left: 50px;`

```
ul li:nth-child(5) {  
  padding-left: 50px;
}​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/jHv7L/)**